# Encapsulate properties and methods in framework header files

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, private, encapsulation

My goal is to build a framework, but hide some methods and properties from public headers

The point is that framework has everything built in, but different versions must have some properties and methods hidden

I am looking for some method either to delete some marked properties from built headers or to avoid them to be added during the build phase.

In my mind it should be something like this:

```
@interface MyClass

@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass1* instance1;

#AVAILABLE FROM 1.0.2
@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass2* instance2;

#AVAILABLE FROM 1.0.3
@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass3* instance3;

- (void) method1;

#AVAILABLE FROM 1.0.3
- (void) method2;

@end
```

So if i set some predefined version value or project version value (doesn't really matter) to 1.0.2
then instance1, instance2 and method1 SHOULD BE in the framework headers, but 
instance3 and method2 will be available only in version 1.0.3 or higher

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the pre-compilation step:

a) In the project for every buildTarget create a #def value like version(`#define VERSION 1.0`). Every buildTarget should have a different version and will represent the different versions of your FW. To do that go to the project options, the build target options-> build settings-> PRECOMPILER MACROS

b) Create a pre-compiler function like GREATER THAN:
`#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) v>= VERSION` (that can be defined in the .pch)

c) at the headers put

```
  #if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(1.0.2))
  property (strong, nonatomic) SomeClass2* instance2;
  #endif
```

etc

Do you think that solves your problem.

if you do that the precompiler will jump the code that is under his version

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! It looks right to me except if precompiler takes props and methods from the build, then my code may not work. The goal is to take them from headers, but leave them in the build. Anyway, I very appreciate your help, let me check if this works for me.

Comment: My proposition for you is that if it's properties, you can declare it in headers with this method and implement it instead of synthesyze it. To declare the vars you can do it in an extension in the .m file. For the methods it's a methos that I think it can helps you... You can use the precompiler to put `@private` in the good point. I put a change in the answer...

Comment: Sorry forgot about that.... We can't use private for methods, only for declared values... but you can create it conditionally on the extension of the declaration in .m...

Comment: I ended up with a batch script in build phases which searches for marked blocks in framework headers and removes them, so user is not able to see them but my framework still can use them. I used your idea of predefinition in .pch so your answer helped me. thanks.